# How do I backup my iPhone and restore it on another machine?

Tags: backup, itunes, iphone

How do I backup my iPhone and restore it on another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install iTunes on the other machine and sync your iPhone with that machine. iTunes will automatically backup your device so you can restore it whenever it is needed.

iTunes will automatically backup your iPhone when you sync it, or when you update or restore it.

You may have to move your whole iTunes library to your new computer. You could make a backup of your library by going `File > Library > Backup to disk` and then load the resulting disks into the new computer. Alternatively, you could try [manually moving](http://hifiblog.com/past/2006/05/11/howto-move-your-itunes-music-while-preserving-library-data-when-you-dont-let-itunes-manage-your-music-library/)  your library.

Comment: Does this answer apply to both Windows and Mac?

Comment: It should. They are mostly the same.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414):

> ### Backing up your iPhone or iPod touch
>
> Your iPhone and/or iPod touch is
>   backed up by iTunes each time you:
>
> - Sync with iTunes (automatically on the first sync, every time you
>     connect it to the computer)
> - Update in iTunes (occurs automatically without prompting)
> - Restore in iTunes (prompts you to create a backup before the restore
>     process begins)
>
> Although iTunes backs up most of your
>   iPhone and iPod touch settings,
>   downloaded applications, your audio,
>   video, and photo content are not
>   included in the backup.
>
> If restoring from an iTunes backup,
>   your iPhone and iPod touch settings,
>   downloaded applications, audio, video,
>   and photo contents will re-sync to the
>   device because the "Sync" option under
>   the respective tabs will be checked in
>   iTunes when restoring from a backup.
>   If you choose to restore your device
>   as a new user, downloaded
>   applications, audio, video, and photo
>   content will not be sync until you
>   select the "Sync" option in iTunes
>   under each tab.
>
> ### Restoring your iPhone or iPod touch
>
> Using the Restore function for your
>   iPhone or iPod touch is part of
>   standard troubleshooting procedure.
>   Restoring your device will erase all
>   data from your iPhone or iPod touch,
>   including songs, videos, contacts,
>   photos, calendar information, and any
>   other data. All iPhone or iPod touch
>   settings are restored to their factory
>   condition.
>
> Whenever you restore your iPhone or
>   iPod touch, Apple highly recommends
>   that you perform a sync prior to
>   restoring in order to back up any
>   changes since your last sync. If you
>   have movie rentals on the device, see
>   [this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1415#caution) before restoring.
>
> Use the following steps to restore
>   your iPhone or iPod touch:
>
> 1. Make sure you have the latest version of iTunes installed and
>      running before attempting to update.
> 2. Connect your iPhone or iPod touch to your computer.
> 3. Select your iPhone or iPod touch when it appears in iTunes under
>      Devices.
> 4. Select the Summary tab.
> 5. Select the Restore option.
> 6. When prompted to back up your iPhone or iPod touch's settings before
>      restoring, select the Back Up option. If have
>      just backed up the device, it is not
>      necessary to create another.
> 7. Select the Restore option when iTunes prompts you (As long as you've
>      backed up your device, you should not
>      have to worry about restoring your
>      phone).
> 8. Once the restore process has completed the iPhone or iPod touch
>      restarts and displays the Apple logo
>      while starting up.
>
>    iPhone only: For the iPhone only, after a restore, the iPhone
>      displays the "Connect to iTunes"
>      screen. Keep your device connected
>      until the "Connect to iTunes" screen
>      goes away or you see "iPhone is
>      activated." If iTunes does not have an
>      Internet connection, you cannot
>      complete this step.
> 9. The final step is to restore your iPhone or iPod touch from a
>      previous backup.
>        Select the back up you want for your iPhone or iPod touch and select
>      the Continue button in order to
>      complete your device's restoration.

Comment: this kb is about restoring iPhone in the same computer

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you sync your iPhone to a new PC/Mac, you are able to sync it's contacts, calendar, call history to the new computer. Only the videos, photos, and music can't be sync *FROM* the iPhone.

If the question you ask was about how to sync the essential content (i.e. contacts etc), you have no need to worry since iTunes will merge the contacts from your iPhone with the contacts in your new PC/Mac.

Of course later on you'll have to migrate your iTunes library to your new computer afterwards